# Создание файла png из массива rgb [javascript]

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив RGB и я хочу создать из него png файл. Я знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью canvas. Но проблема в canvas в том, что он создает 32bit изображения, а мне надо 24bit. Как это можно сделать без canvas?

Comment: @Node_pro это мой вопрос, но преобразование jpeg в png зашло в тупик

Comment: https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js/

Comment: @AlexeyTen вы человечище! Наконец помогло, спасибо! Я получил 24bit png